# SMTP client to send search results

Tags: c#, classes, email

I have the following working code to send search results via e-mail.  Since we have segregated domains that cannot talk to each other, the program needs to support multiple SMTP servers.

```
private static int[] _SMTPport = new int[2] { 25, 587 };
private static string[] _SMTPserver = new string[4]
{
  "smtp.domain1.local",
  "smtp.domain2.local",
  "smtp.domain3.local",
  "smtp.domain4.local" 
};

switch (sUserDomain) 
{
  case: "domain1":
  case: "DOMAIN1":
    Send_Email(_SMTPserver[0], _SMTPport[0], false); 
    break;
  case: "domain2":
  case: "DOMAIN2":
    Send_Email(_SMTPserver[0], _SMTPport[0], false); 
    break;
  case: "domain3":
  case: "DOMAIN3":
    Send_Email(_SMTPserver[0], _SMTPport[0], false); 
    break;
  case: "domain4":
  case: "DOMAIN4":
    Send_Email(_SMTPserver[0], _SMTPport[0], false); 
    break;
  default:
    Send_Email(_SMTPserver[3], _SMTPport[0], false);
    break;
}

private static void Send_Email(string _server, int _port, bool _ssl)
{
  StringBuilder emailString = new StringBuilder();
  MailMessage mMessage = new MailMessage();

  SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(_server);
  smtpClient.Port = _port;
  smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

  if (_ssl.Equals(true)) 
  { smtpClient.EnableSsl = true; }

  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
  { return true; };

  mMessage.From = new MailAddress("from-address");
  mMessage.To.Add(sEmailAddress);

  mMessage.Subject = "Logs from " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + " searched " + sDate + " for " + sSearchTerm;
  emailString.Append("<p style='font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'>Here are the file(s) on <b>" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "</b> under <b>" + sDate + "</b> that contain <b><i>" + sSearchTerm + "</i><b></p><br/><br/>");
  emailString.AppendLine("<table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'><tbody><tr><td style='padding:5px;background-color:rgb(169, 169, 169);color:white;'>Filenames</td></tr>");
  int count = 0;
  foreach (var item in logList)
 {
   if (count % 2 == 0)
   {
     emailString.AppendLine("<tr><td style='background-color:#bada55;border-collapse:collapse;'>" + Path.GetFileName(item) + "</td></tr>");
   }
   else
  {
    emailString.AppendLine("<tr><td style='background-color:#55bada;border-collapse:collapse;'>" + Path.GetFileName(item) + "</td></tr>");
  }
  count++;
}
emailString.Append("</tr></tbody></table>");
mMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

mMessage.Body = emailString.ToString();
```

---

I'm working on converting it to be object-oriented.  My concern is that I need to add multiple items to the message before sending.  Here is what I have so far — am I on the correct path?

```
public class EmailClass
{
  private string _domain;
  private string _emailaddress;
  private string _fromaddress;
  private string _subject;
  private List<string> _message = new List<string>();

  public string Domain
  {
    get { return _domain; }
    set { _domain = value; }
  }

  public string EmailAddress
  {
    get { return _emailaddress; }
    set { _emailaddress = value; }
  }

  public string FromAddress
  {
    get { return _fromaddress; }
    set { _fromaddress = value; }
  }

  public string Subject
  {
    get { return _subject; }
    set { _subject = value; }
  }
  public List<string> Message
  {
    get { return _message; }
    set { _message = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Can you describe some more about what your code does? How much do you know about C# classes? I would recommend trying to write a class implementation and then coming here and ask for a review on it. It sounds like you already know what you need to do.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg My code uses our companies smtp relays to send email messages based on intuit. I don't know very much about C# classes

Comment: Perhaps what you might need is a tutorial on C# classes?

Comment: I have been looking at this one http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpSimpleClass.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SRP - single responsibility principle**

The `Send_Email()` method is responsible for to many things.
The method is

1. creating and configuring a `SmtpClient`
2. creating and configuring a `MailMessage`
3. composing the body of the `MailMessage`

This should be extracted to separate methods.

So let us refactor this method.

First we write a method to create a `SmtpClient`.

```
private SmtpClient GetSmtpClient(string serverAddress, int serverPort, bool enableSsl)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(serverAddress);
    smtpClient.Port = serverPort;
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = enableSsl;

    return smtpClient;
}
```

This had been pretty easy, hadn't it ? So, next we add a method composing the `Subject` by using the [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
private String ComposeSubject(LogResult logResult) 
{
    return String.Format("Logs from {0} searched {1} for {2}", logResult.ComputerName, logResult.SearchDate, logResult.SearchTerm);
}
```

But wait, what is `LogResult` ? That is a class we need to create, so let us do it. As we see it should have at least the properties ComputerName, SearchDate and SearchTerm. We add also a [`ReadOnlyCollection<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `FileNames` property.

```
public class LogResult
{
    public String ComputerName { get; private set; }
    public DateTime SearchDate { get; private set; }
    public String SearchTerm { get; private set; }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<String> FileNames { get; private set; }

    public LogResult(String computerName, DateTime searchDate, String searchTerm, List<String> logList)
    {
        ComputerName = computerName;
        SearchDate = searchDate;
        SearchTerm = searchTerm;
        FileNames = ToFileNames(logList);
    }

    public LogResult(DateTime searchDate, String searchTerm, List<String> logList)
        : this(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME"), searchDate, searchTerm, logList)
    { }

    private ReadOnlyCollection<String> ToFileNames(List<String> logList)
    {
        IList<String> fileNames = new List<String>(logList.Count);
        foreach (String completeFileName in logList)
        {
            fileNames.Add(Path.GetFileName(completeFileName));
        }
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<String>(fileNames);
    }
}
```

So now we will use this class to also compose the email body. Here we are using the feature of the `StringBuilder` that it is returning a `StringBuilder` for calling the `AppendXX()` methods. So we can call `StringBuilder.Append().Append()...`we are using also the [`StringBuilder.AppendFormat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cazfhf32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
private String ComposeMailBody(LogResult logResult)
{
    StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder(1024);

    bodyBuilder.Append("<p style='font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'>")
        .AppendFormat("Here are the file(s) on <b> {0}", logResult.ComputerName)
        .AppendFormat("</b> under <b>{0}", logResult.SearchDate)
        .AppendFormat("</b> that contain <b><i>{0}</i><b></p><br/><br/>",logResult.SearchTerm)
        .AppendLine("<table width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'><tbody><tr><td style='padding:5px;background-color:rgb(169, 169, 169);color:white;'>Filenames</td></tr>");

    int count = 0;
    foreach (String fileName in logResult.FileNames)
    {
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            bodyBuilder.AppendFormat("<tr><td style='background-color:#bada55;border-collapse:collapse;'>{0}</td></tr>",fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            bodyBuilder.AppendFormat("<tr><td style='background-color:#55bada;border-collapse:collapse;'>{0}</td></tr>",fileName);
        }
        count++;
    }
    bodyBuilder.Append("</tr></tbody></table>");

    return bodyBuilder.ToString();
}
```

The last method we introduce is for creating a MailMessage.

```
private MailMessage CreateMessage(LogResult logResult, String receiver)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage("from-address", receiver);
    message.Subject = ComposeSubkject(logResult);
    message.Body = ComposeMailBody(logResult);

    return message;
}
```

Now the former `Send_Email()` method would look like

```
private static void SendEmail(string server, int port, bool ssl)
{
    LogResult logResult = new LogResult(sDate ,sSearchTerm, logList);
    SmtpClient smtpClient = GetSmtpClient(server, port, ssl);
    MailMessage message = CreateMailMessage(sEmailAddress);

    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

**EmailClass**

Using auto properties will reduce your code a lot. Auto properties are properties with a hidden backing field generated by the compiler.

```
public class EmailClass
{
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string FromAddress { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public List<string> Message { get; set; }

}
```

**Naming**

Based on the [naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method names should be named using `PascalCase` casing. So `Send_Email` should be renamed to `SendEmail`.
Based on the same guidlines method parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing. the signature of the former `Send_Email()` method should look like

```
private static void SendEmail(string server, int port, bool ssl)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is in addition to Heslacher's great review.

I'm not a big fan of the arrays you define at the start, since a line like this sin't really telling me anything:

```
Send_Email(_SMTPserver[0], _SMTPport[0], false);
```

I'd put the values of those arrays in a static class and expose them as const strings/int, e.g.

```
internal static class SmtpPort
{
    public const int TwentyFive = 25;
}

internal static class SmtpServer
{
    public const string Domain1 = "smtp.domain1.local";
}
```

That way your call becomes far more readable:

```
Send_Email(SmtpServer.Domain1, SmtpPort.TwentyFive, false);
```

Note that SMTP [shouldn't be all capitals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Do capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more
>   characters, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.
>
> A class named XmlWriter is an example of a long acronym used as the
>   first word of a Pascal-cased identifier. A parameter named htmlReader
>   is an example of a long acronym used as the first word of a
>   camel-cased identifier.

I'd also eliminate the need for multiple cases in your switch by simply converting sUserDomain first:

```
switch (sUserDomain.ToLower()) 
{
  case: "domain1":
    Send_Email(_SMTPserver[0], _SMTPport[0], false); 
    break;
  case: "domain2":
    Send_Email(_SMTPserver[0], _SMTPport[0], false); 
    break;
}
```

Note that sUserDomain is a bad variable name: Hungarian notation [is frowned upon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).